¿Como puedo usar un software de laravel de una version anterior(7.0)?
Al momento de clonar un repositorio y ejecutar el codigo de laravel con php artisan serve
dado a que la version de laravel es antigua (7.0) me sale este error en la consola
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\sistema-prestamos\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349 
He intentado ejecutar composer update pero me sigue repitiendo el mismo error
Este es mi composer.json
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
  },



ArrayAccess es una clase de PHP. ¿tu problema será por la versión de PHP? Quizás tienes un PHP muy moderno.
